# Generating scripts for database role membership in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, scripting, membership, role

I have a database with a lot of users in it. Those users belong to different built-in roles in the DB (eg db_ddladmin).

I want to generate a script that creates those same users with the same role assignments to use in a different database. SQL Management Studio seems to only generate sp_addrolemember calls for user-defined roles, not the build-in ones. Is there any way to make it script all roles?

Perhaps there is any other, better tool for generating database scripts from an existing database (preferably, but not necessarily, free)?

Comment: This should be scriptable via use of the system tables/views. If no one else posts, I'll work something up later on.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Information about a database's users and the roles they are assigned to are made available in system views
sys.database_principals and sys.database_role_members. Review this data with these queries:

```
select * from sys.database_principals
select * from sys.database_role_members
```

I'll assume you have database users and roles configured in database A, and you want them copied over to database B. To create the users in the target database:

- Run the following query in database A
- Cut, paste, REVIEW, and run the resulting script in database B

.

```
SELECT 'CREATE USER [' + name + '] for login [' + name + ']'
 from sys.database_principals
 where Type = 'U'
  and name <> 'dbo'
```

To configure the new users in B with the same roles as they have in A:

- Run the following query in database A
- Cut, paste, REVIEW, and run the resulting script in database B

.

```
SELECT 'EXECUTE sp_addrolemember ''' + roles.name + ''', ''' + users.name + ''''
 from sys.database_principals users
  inner join sys.database_role_members link
   on link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id
  inner join sys.database_principals roles
   on roles.principal_id = link.role_principal_id
```

Always review these scripts. There may be exceptions or special cases going on, and you just don't want to mess up security.

If the new database is on a different SQL Server instance, you will have to create the SQL logins first. If you have user-defined roles,
you will need to recreate them first. (Roles and the permissions assigned to them are *very* open-ended, and I don't ever want to be in a situation where I'd need to do that!)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! :)

Comment: perfect, a script to create a script.. i had tried scripting logins with Generate Script... but ran into permission issues, no issues now, thanks.

Comment: Just a note, if your database has a case sensitive collation, it should be sp_addrolemember. I edited the answer above to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option from Idera: http://www.idera.com/Products/Free-Tools/SQL-permissions/
It generates logins and permissions and may help you accomplish what you are attempting.

Answer (score 0):

For DB  User Roles

```
SELECT 'CREATE ROLE [' + name + ']' 
  FROM sys.database_principals 
  where type='R' and is_fixed_role = 0 and name != 'public'
```

Comment: When writing answers, try formatting them. Stackoverflow uses markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the original answer to use the new `ALTER ROLE` syntax:

```
SELECT 'ALTER ROLE  [' + roles.name + '] ADD MEMBER [' + users.name + '];'
from sys.database_principals users
inner join sys.database_role_members link
on link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id
inner join sys.database_principals roles
on roles.principal_id = link.role_principal_id
where users.name = 'MyUser'
```

This is database specific - run it in the database you want to extract roles for